# Landau's fermi liquid theory: With four parameters I can fit an elephant, and with five I can make him wiggle his trunk!

Tags: fermi-liquids

I have no intention of mocking Landau's theory by the quote of John von Neumann (Attributed to von Neumann by Enrico Fermi). I want to understand why we are saying this theory of Landau is remarkably successful. There are many parameters in the theory and I don't see it's beauty. I'm sure one with deep insight into this theory can help us to see in what sense it is successful?

Comment: Just a very marginal comment. If I correctly remember, that von Neumann's statement was actually stated by E. Fermi ("my friend J. von Neumann would have said...") as an overall comment on some F. Dyson's theory on nuclear forces. It seems that Dyson decided to leave physics consequenty, and he started to think of his self as an "applied mathematician".

Comment: @ValterMoretti [here you go](http://www.webofstories.com/play/freeman.dyson/94;jsessionid=ABD198C1859F567F8718C1CD83BF9E3C)! Beautiful stuff (at around 2:00) :) The entire web of stories interview (about 4 hours) is nice, and I recommend it strongly.

Comment: As a matter of fact, there is no theoretical limit for the microscopic complexity of the systems that the Landau model attempts to describe (you could, for instance, introduce as many atomic or molecular species as you can find in the chemistry lab into a particular implementation). So it's actually quite surprising, that in many cases such a simple model does such a good job. The genome of the African elephant, by the way, is approx. 3.1Gb long... I doubt that any serious physicist has any hopes of describing that with a mere four parameters. ;-)

Comment: People sometimes say it is a miracle but the theory itself is just (at least as far as I understand) the same as ideal Fermi gas model which produces the similar thermodynamical properties and you have some parameters to fit them to experimental data, is this all it can do or there are other fascinating results?

Answer (score 3):

The wonderful thing about Landau Fermi liquid theory is that it is a general theory for any system which can be described by a Fermi surface at low temperatures and has fermionic excitations. For example, while most metals have complicated interactions, by integrating out the interactions below the fermi surface we arrive at an effective theory of fermionic excitations with a renormalized mass. This explains why metals are so well described by ideal fermi gasses as the concept of fermionic excitations above the Fermi surface still holds although there are interactions. A condition for the applicability is that the interaction does not cause instabilities, which ensures the concept of fermi surface survives.  For attractive interactions the Fermi liquid theory starts to breakdown and can lead to Cooper pairs, ie superconductivity. The most wonderful thing is that the effective mass and effective interaction (and other relevant effective parameters) can be derived from the microscopic theory, but this microscopic theory is not necessary once the value of these effective parameters are known.